# Ограничение COOKIE - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, cookie

В  WP в корзину гость добавляет максимум 9 товаров, после чего вылетает ошибка 502. Немного подумав, я понял, что скорее всего тут срабатывает ограничение в объеме данных куки. Если я прав, то что можно придумать или может есть какие-то готовые решения ?

```
    public function foodbakery_restaurant_add_menu_item() {
            global $foodbakery_plugin_options, $current_user;
            $foodbakery_currency_sign = foodbakery_get_currency_sign();
            $rand_numb = rand(10000000, 99999999);
            $restaurant_id = foodbakery_get_input('_rid', 0);
            $menu_cat_id = foodbakery_get_input('menu_cat_id', 0);
            $menu_item_id = foodbakery_get_input('menu_id', 0);
            $menu_updating = isset($_POST['act_updating']) ? $_POST['act_updating'] : '';
            $menu_extra_atts = isset($_POST['extra_atts']) ? $_POST['extra_atts'] : '';
            $extra_name = isset($_POST['extra_name']) ? $_POST['extra_name'] : '';
            $unique_menu_id = isset($_POST['menu_unique_id_']) ? $_POST['menu_unique_id_'] : '';
            $restaurant_menu_list = get_post_meta($restaurant_id, 'foodbakery_menu_items', true);



            $jus_pl = false;
            if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
                $jus_pl = true;

            } else {
                $user_id = $current_user->ID;
                $publisher_id = foodbakery_company_id_form_user_id($user_id);

                if ($publisher_id != '') {
                    $publisher_type = get_post_meta($publisher_id, 'foodbakery_publisher_profile_type', true);
                    if ($publisher_type != 'restaurant' && $publisher_type != '') {

                        $menu_t_price = 0;

                        // menu title
                        $this_item_title = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_title']) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_title'] : '';

                        // menu price
                        $this_item_price = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_price']) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_price'] : '';
$this_item_price2 = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_price2']) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_price2'] : '';
                        $menu_t_price += floatval($this_item_price);
                        $extras_arra = array();
                        $extras_html = '';
                        if ($menu_extra_atts != '') {

                            $menu_extra_atts = explode(',', $menu_extra_atts);
                            $extra_name = explode(',', $extra_name);
                            if (is_array($menu_extra_atts)) {
                                // menu extras
                                $this_item_extras = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_extra']) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_extra'] : '';

                                $menu_ext_counter = 0;
                                foreach ($menu_extra_atts as $key => $menu_extra_att) {
                                    //foreach ($menu_extra_atts as $menu_extra_att) {
                                    $this_item_heading = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_extra']['heading'][$extra_name[$key]]) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_extra']['heading'][$extra_name[$key]] : '';
                                    $menu_extra_at_label = isset($this_item_extras[$extra_name[$key]]['title'][$menu_extra_att]) ? $this_item_extras[$extra_name[$key]]['title'][$menu_extra_att] : '';
                                    $menu_extra_at_price = isset($this_item_extras[$extra_name[$key]]['price'][$menu_extra_att]) ? $this_item_extras[$extra_name[$key]]['price'][$menu_extra_att] : '';

                                    $extras_arra[] = array(
                                        'title' => $menu_extra_at_label,
                                        'price' => $menu_extra_at_price,
                                        'title_id' => $extra_name[$key],
                                        'menu_item_id' => $menu_extra_att,
                                    );

                                    $extras_html .= '<li>' . $this_item_heading . ' - ' . $menu_extra_at_label . ' : <span class="category-price">' . foodbakery_get_currency($menu_extra_at_price, true) . '</span></li>';

                                    $menu_t_price += floatval($menu_extra_at_price);

                                    $menu_ext_counter ++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $get_added_menus = get_transient('add_menu_items_' . $publisher_id);

                        if (empty($get_added_menus) && isset($_COOKIE['add_menu_items_temp']) && !is_user_logged_in()) {
                            $get_added_menus = unserialize(stripslashes($_COOKIE['add_menu_items_temp']));
                        }

                        if ($menu_updating == 'true') {
                            $menu_index = isset($_POST['menu_index']) ? $_POST['menu_index'] : '';
                            if (isset($get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][$menu_index])) {
                                $updated_menu = array(
                                    'menu_cat_id' => $menu_cat_id,
                                    'menu_id' => $menu_item_id,
                                    'price' => $this_item_price,
                                    'price2' => $this_item_price2,
                                    'unique_id' => $rand_numb,
                                    'unique_menu_id' => $unique_menu_id,
                                    'extras' => $extras_arra,
                                );
                                $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][$menu_index] = $updated_menu;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (is_array($get_added_menus) && sizeof($get_added_menus) > 0) {

                                $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][] = array(
                                    'menu_cat_id' => $menu_cat_id,
                                    'menu_id' => $menu_item_id,
                                    'price' => $this_item_price,
                                      'price2' => $this_item_price2,
                                    'unique_id' => $rand_numb,
                                    'unique_menu_id' => $unique_menu_id,
                                    'extras' => $extras_arra,
                                );
                            } else {
                                $get_added_menus = array();
                                $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][] = array(
                                    'menu_cat_id' => $menu_cat_id,
                                    'menu_id' => $menu_item_id,
                                    'price' => $this_item_price,
                                    'price2' => $this_item_price2,
                                    'unique_id' => $rand_numb,
                                    'unique_menu_id' => $unique_menu_id,
                                    'extras' => $extras_arra,
                                );
                            }
                        }

                        $li_html = '
                <li id="menu-added-' . $rand_numb . '" data-pr="' . foodbakery_get_currency($menu_t_price, false, '', '', false) . '" data-conpr="' . foodbakery_get_currency($menu_t_price, false, '', '', true) . '">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-cross dev-remove-menu-item"><i class=" icon-cross3"></i></a>
                    <a>' . $this_item_title . '</a>
                    <span class="category-price">' . foodbakery_get_currency($this_item_price, true) . '</span>';
                        if ($extras_html != '') {
                            $li_html .= '<ul>';
                            $li_html .= $extras_html;
                            $li_html .= '</ul>';

                            $popup_id = 'edit_extras-' . $menu_cat_id . '-' . $menu_item_id;
                            $data_id = $menu_item_id;
                            $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
                            $array_latest_added_menu = count($get_added_menus[$restaurant_id]) - 1;
                            $unique_id = $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][$array_latest_added_menu]['unique_id'];
                            $extra_child_menu_id = $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][$array_latest_added_menu]['extra_child_menu_id'];
                            $li_html .= '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit-menu-item" onClick="foodbakery_edit_extra_menu_item(\'' . $popup_id . '\',\'' . $data_id . '\',\'' . $menu_cat_id . '\',\'' . $rand_numb . '\',\'' . $ajax_url . '\',\'' . $restaurant_id . '\',\'' . $unique_id . '\',\'' . $unique_menu_id . '\',\'' . $extra_child_menu_id . '\');">' . esc_html__('Edit', 'foodbakery') . '</a>';
                            //$li_html .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#extras-' . $menu_cat_id . '-' . $menu_item_id . '" data-id="' . $menu_item_id . '" data-cid="' . $menu_cat_id . '" data-rand="' . $rand_numb . '" class="update-menu dev-update-menu-btn">' . esc_html__('Edit', 'foodbakery') . '</a>';
                        }
                        $li_html .= '
                        </li>';
                        set_transient('add_menu_items_' . $publisher_id, $get_added_menus, 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

                        if ($menu_updating == 'true') {
                            //$json = array('msg' => esc_html__('Menu item have been updated in your basket.', 'foodbakery'), 'type' => 'success', 'li_html' => $li_html);
                            $json = array('li_html' => $li_html);
                        } else {
                            //$json = array('msg' => esc_html__('Menu item have been added in your basket', 'foodbakery'), 'type' => 'success', 'li_html' => $li_html);
                            $json = array('li_html' => $li_html);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $jus_pl = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    $jus_pl = true;
                }
            }
            if ($jus_pl) {
                $menu_t_price = 0;

                // menu title
                $this_item_title = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_title']) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_title'] : '';

                // menu price
                $this_item_price = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_price']) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_price'] : '';
                 $this_item_price2 = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_price2']) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_price2'] : '';

                $menu_t_price += floatval($this_item_price);
                $extras_arra = array();
                $extras_html = '';
                if ($menu_extra_atts != '') {

                    $menu_extra_atts = explode(',', $menu_extra_atts);
                    $extra_name = explode(',', $extra_name);
                    if (is_array($menu_extra_atts)) {
                        // menu extras
                        $this_item_extras = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_extra']) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_extra'] : '';

                        //  $menu_ext_counter = 0;

                        foreach ($menu_extra_atts as $key => $menu_extra_att) {


                            $this_item_heading = isset($restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_extra']['heading'][$extra_name[$key]]) ? $restaurant_menu_list[$menu_item_id]['menu_item_extra']['heading'][$extra_name[$key]] : '';
                            $menu_extra_at_label = isset($this_item_extras[$extra_name[$key]]['title'][$menu_extra_att]) ? $this_item_extras[$extra_name[$key]]['title'][$menu_extra_att] : '';
                            $menu_extra_at_price = isset($this_item_extras[$extra_name[$key]]['price'][$menu_extra_att]) ? $this_item_extras[$extra_name[$key]]['price'][$menu_extra_att] : '';

                            $extras_arra[] = array(
                                'title' => $menu_extra_at_label,
                                'price' => $menu_extra_at_price,
                                'title_id' => $extra_name[$key],
                                'menu_item_id' => $menu_extra_att,
                            );

                            $extras_html .= '<li>' . $this_item_heading . ' - ' . $menu_extra_at_label . ' : <span class="category-price">' . foodbakery_get_currency($menu_extra_at_price, true) . '</span></li>';

                            $menu_t_price += floatval($menu_extra_at_price);

                            // $menu_ext_counter ++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $get_added_menus = '';

                if (isset($_COOKIE['add_menu_items_temp'])) {
                    $get_added_menus = unserialize(stripslashes($_COOKIE['add_menu_items_temp']));
                }

                if ($menu_updating == 'true') {
                    $menu_index = isset($_POST['menu_index']) ? $_POST['menu_index'] : '';
                    if (isset($get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][$menu_index])) {
                        $updated_menu = array(
                            'menu_cat_id' => $menu_cat_id,
                            'menu_id' => $menu_item_id,
                            'price' => $this_item_price,
                            'price2' => $this_item_price2,
                            'unique_id' => $rand_numb,
                            'unique_menu_id' => $unique_menu_id,
                            'extra_child_menu_id' => rand(10000000, 99999999),
                            'extras' => $extras_arra,
                        );
                        $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][$menu_index] = $updated_menu;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (is_array($get_added_menus) && sizeof($get_added_menus) > 0) {

                        $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][] = array(
                            'menu_cat_id' => $menu_cat_id,
                            'menu_id' => $menu_item_id,
                            'price' => $this_item_price,
                            'price2' => $this_item_price2,
                            'unique_id' => $rand_numb,
                            'unique_menu_id' => $unique_menu_id,
                            'extra_child_menu_id' => rand(10000000, 99999999),
                            'extras' => $extras_arra,
                        );
                    } else {
                        $get_added_menus = array();
                        $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][] = array(
                            'menu_cat_id' => $menu_cat_id,
                            'menu_id' => $menu_item_id,
                            'price' => $this_item_price,
                            'price2' => $this_item_price2,
                            'unique_id' => $rand_numb,
                            'unique_menu_id' => $unique_menu_id,
                            'extras' => $extras_arra,
                        );
                    }
                }
                $li_html = '
                <li id="menu-added-' . $rand_numb . '" data-pr="' . foodbakery_get_currency($menu_t_price, false, '', '', false) . '" data-conpr="' . foodbakery_get_currency($menu_t_price, false, '', '', true) . '">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-cross dev-remove-menu-item"><i class=" icon-cross3"></i></a>
                <a>' . $this_item_title . '</a>
                <span class="category-price">' . foodbakery_get_currency($this_item_price, true) . '</span>';
                if ($extras_html != '') {
                    $li_html .= '<ul>';
                    $li_html .= $extras_html;
                    $li_html .= '</ul>';
                    $popup_id = 'edit_extras-' . $menu_cat_id . '-' . $menu_item_id;
                    $data_id = $menu_item_id;
                    $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
                    $array_latest_added_menu = count($get_added_menus[$restaurant_id]) - 1;
                    $unique_id = $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][$array_latest_added_menu]['unique_id'];
                    $extra_child_menu_id = $get_added_menus[$restaurant_id][$array_latest_added_menu]['extra_child_menu_id'];
                    $li_html .= '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit-menu-item" onClick="foodbakery_edit_extra_menu_item(\'' . $popup_id . '\',\'' . $data_id . '\',\'' . $menu_cat_id . '\',\'' . $rand_numb . '\',\'' . $ajax_url . '\',\'' . $restaurant_id . '\',\'' . $unique_id . '\',\'' . $unique_menu_id . '\',\'' . $extra_child_menu_id . '\');">' . esc_html__('Edit', 'foodbakery') . '</a>';
                }
                $li_html .= '</li>';
                setcookie('add_menu_items_temp', serialize($get_added_menus), time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/');
                if ($menu_updating == 'true') {
                    //$json = array( 'msg' => esc_html__('Menu item have been updated in your basket.', 'foodbakery'), 'type' => 'success', 'li_html' => $li_html );
                    $json = array('li_html' => $li_html);
                } else {
                    //$json = array( 'msg' => esc_html__('Menu item have been added in your basket', 'foodbakery'), 'type' => 'success', 'li_html' => $li_html );
                    $json = array('li_html' => $li_html);
                }
            }

            echo json_encode($json);

            die;
        }
```

Comment: Не надо предполагать, смотрите логи сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас веб сервер **nginx**, то можно добавить ограничения для макс размера кук, включив буфер в разделе **http**

```
   proxy_buffering          on;
   proxy_buffers         4 64k;
   proxy_buffer_size       32k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
```

если же **apache2** тогда в конфиги в раздел **VirtualHost** домена

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
   ....
   ServerName localhost
   LimitRequestFieldSize 16384 #тут нужное вам число, смотрите в документацыии apache2
   ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Смотрите сколько у вас по дефолту стоит, а лучше в куках не хранить много информации, так как они каждый раз летят на сервер и это дополнительная нагрузка, храните идентификаторы, а лучше саму корзину можно вязать по сессии пользователя если он не залогине к относительной записи в бд.